# Copy files from calling repo to action

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions, building-github-actions

I want to create a github docker container action that uses files from the repository using the action.

Do I need to check the repository out by myself or can I specify a point where the files are copied if it was checked out before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github actions do not have a concept of repository or branch. Each workflow is run in a container and only has that container to interact with.

Actions can have [`inputs`](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#inputs). You can create an input that should point to the location of the user's repository.

#### In your action.yml:

```
inputs:
  repo_path:
    description: 'The path to the repository in the current environment'
    required: true
```

In your code, you can check for the `repo_path` input to get the path to the repository on the file system.

You can also check if the `GITHUB_WORKSPACE` points to a git repository which means that the user had used the [`actions/checkout`](https://github.com/actions/checkout) action in a prior step.